# How to create the border height of a child div as same as the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have a child div with some padding. But when I apply border-right on the child div, then how can I get it in full height? Here's the code:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
</div>

.parent{
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.child{
  width: 25%;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

The output of my current code: 
[image]

What I actually want: 
[image]

I am newbie, it will be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Remove top and bottom margins from child element(s), `h2` has default margins set by browser. Other way to do it is to set `.child {overflow: hidden;}`, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5p3Lawe2/1/).

Comment: See this -- https://jsfiddle.net/uf9dwtwc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing default `margin` of `<h1>` element and then using `padding` you can align the `text` to center on parent div and set `height:100%` to child div, as below,

```css
.parent{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height:40px;
}
.child{
  width: 25%;
  height:100%;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
h2{
  margin:0;
  padding-top:8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h2>Content</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome @Gamer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `h2` tag gets default top and bottom margins from the browser. You can either set those to zero (example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5p3Lawe2/2/)):

```
h2 { margin: 0 }
```

Or, if you want to keep them, than set the child's container overflow to hidden:

```
.child {overflow: hidden;}
```

Example below:

```css
.parent {
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.child {
    width: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <h2>Content</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5p3Lawe2/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit the parent's maximum height. Try adding this into your.child ,

```
.child{
 max-height:parent;
}
```